# Как вызвать функцию @IBAction из другой функции?

Tags: xcode, swift, функции

Есть функция longTap, так вот ее нужно вызвать из другой аналогичной функции. Как это сделать?

```
@IBAction func longTap(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Сохранение изображения", message: "Вы действительно хотите сохранить изображение?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Да", style: .Default, handler: { (alertAction) -> Void in
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image.image!, nil, #selector(ShowPhotoViewController.showSavedPhotoStatus), nil)
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Нет", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Если у вас есть возможность сделать sender необязательным (добавить ?) `@IBAction func longTap(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer?)`, то потом можно вызвать `self.longTap(nil)`

2) если нет, то вам придется генерировать "искусственный" тап для передачи в метод.

```
let tap: UILongPressGestureRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer()
self.longTap(tap)
```